# How to change a specific string to NA in multiple columns and change column to numeric

Tags: r

I have data in which some of the columns have a mix of `character` and `numeric` data. For example:

```
Sensor  Sensor2   Sensor3
Fail    5         Fail
Fail    5         Fail
Fail    5         Fail
Fail    5         Fail
 5      5         Fail
 6      5         Fail
 8      5         Fail
```

All sensor values should be `numeric`, but R automatically take Sensor1 and Sensor3 as `character` values. I want to replace "Fail" with `NA` or some numeric values, or change the whole Column type to Numeric type so 'Fail' will be changed to `NA` automatically.

My problem is that my data set is really large (sensor data generated every second, with more than 200 variables). I want to identify all the columns that contains 'Fail' and change these columns to `numeric` type.

This is what I tried: I wrote a function

```
function(mydata, value1, value2){
   mydata <- data.frame(lapply(mydata, function(x){              
    gsub(value1, value2 ,x)
     }))
 }
```

This function works, but the only problem is that the whole data frame was changed to `factor` type. I have a mix of `numeric` and `character` that I want to keep the data type correct. So I tried

```
   function(mydata, value1, value2){
    mydata <- data.frame(lapply(mydata, function(x){              
    is.numeric(gsub(value1, value2 ,x))
     }))
   }
```

This changed my columns all to `numeric`, so I missed all the `character` column information.

How can I identify only the 'Fail' columns and make the change only to those columns and update my data frame with the change? Thanks.

Comment: If you use any of the `read.xyz` functions to read your data, e.g. `read.table`, you may use the `na.strings` argument, like `na.strings = c(<all strings you want to be interpreteted as NA)`.

Comment: Related: [Replacing character values with NA in a data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3357743/replacing-character-values-with-na-in-a-data-frame/3357804#3357804)

Comment: Yes, Henrik. I know this methods. I am writing some auto functions that can do this job in a series of data preprocessing/cleaning steps because our users usually just use the data import button to import data themselves. Some cleaning job was done after data was imported. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I create example data with

```
data <- read.table(text = "Sensor  Sensor2   Sensor3
                   Fail    5         Fail
                   Fail    5         Fail
                   Fail    5         Fail
                   Fail    5         Fail
                    5      5         Fail
                    6      5         Fail
                    8      5         Fail",
                   header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
data$char <- letters[1:nrow(data)]
```

The last line introduces an additional column that should not be converted to numeric.

Note that I use `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` to make sure that no columns turn out to be factors. You should definitely also check in your data that it does not contain any factor variables *before* you do the conversion.

The first step is to identify columns that contain `"Fail"` somewhere:

```
fail_cols <- sapply(data, function(x) any(grepl("Fail", x)))
```

Then, I define a function that replaces `"Fail"` with `NA` and converts to numeric:

```
to_num <- function(x) {
  as.numeric(gsub("Fail", NA, x))
}
```

Note that I use `as.numeric()`, not `is.numeric()`. It is the former that converts to numeric, the latter checks whether a variable *is* numeric.

This function is now applied only to those columns of the data frame that contain `"Fail"`:

```
data[fail_cols] <- lapply(data[fail_cols], to_num)
data
##   Sensor Sensor2 Sensor3 char
## 1     NA       5      NA    a
## 2     NA       5      NA    b
## 3     NA       5      NA    c
## 4     NA       5      NA    d
## 5      5       5      NA    e
## 6      6       5      NA    f
## 7      8       5      NA    g
```

You already pointed out in the question that simply using `as.numeric()` instead of `to_num()` would give the same result. It would have, however, the disadvantage that it issues warning messages. In order to avoid these, it may still be helpful to define `to_num()`.

Comment: Hi, Stibu, thanks for your reply, I really appreciate it. I think is.numeric is just a typo, I did have as.numeric in my function. First of all, this step is part of my large data sets preprocessing/cleaning. I don't want to save the previous results as tables and read them again for this step; And secondly I just tried your solution. I think your solution have the same problem with my own solution. All the other character-type columns are changed to NA too.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the point about the columns that should remain characters. Unfortunately, your example data did not contain a column of that sort. Try to create more realistic example data in your next question...

Comment: Thank you very much, Stibu. Problem solved! Appreciate it.