# How to recode variable to only have two variables and set others to missing in R?

Tags: r, subset

[i.stack.imgur.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jBjst.png)/hwans.png

How can I recode the V162034a variable so that I only have the categories for Hillary Clinton and Donald Trump - and set the others as missing values?

Comment: easier to answer the question correctly if you provide the data structure in R not in a screen grab of excel. See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replacing character values with NA in a data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3357743/replacing-character-values-with-na-in-a-data-frame)

Answer (score 1):

```
V162034a[ !(V162034a %in% c("2. Hilary Clinton" ,"1. Donald Trump"))] <- NA
```

This depends on how the data are structured in R, i.e. if it is a column in a data.frame or not.