# How to recode dot to NA in R?

Tags: r, na

I have a data set where missing values have been coded with a dot. I would like to have missing values blank (NA).

Here is the data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(ITEM1 = c(6, 8, '.'),
                   ITEM2 = c(1, 6, 9),
                   ITEM3 = c(4, 2, 5),
                   ITEM4 = c('.', 3, 2),
                   ITEM5 = c(1, 6, 9)
)

df

ITEM1 ITEM2 ITEM3 ITEM4 ITEM5
1     6     1     4     .     1
2     8     6     2     3     6
3     .     9     5     2     9
>
```

Comment: Related :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3357743/replacing-character-values-with-na-in-a-data-frame

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The columns will be `character` class because of the presence of `.`.  Create a logical `matrix` with `==` and assign those elements to `NA`, then convert the data.frame columns to its appropriate type with `type.convert`

```
df[df == "." & !is.na(df)] <- NA
df <- type.convert(df, as.is = TRUE)
```

---

Or in a single step with `replace` (which internally does the assignment)

```
df <- type.convert(replace(df, df == "." & !is.na(df), NA), as.is = TRUE)
```

---

Or another approach is

```
df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) replace(x x %in% '.', NA))
df <- type.convert(df, as.is = TRUE)
```

---

Generally, this can be avoided all together, while reading the data itself i.e. specify `na.strings = "."` in `read.csv/read.table` etc.

Comment: Thank you! This works for the example dataframe. However, when I am trying to apply it to the data set, I get the following error "Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, df == ".", value = NA) : 
  unsupported matrix index in replacement".

Comment: @Marie Can you check the `str(df)`  I assume the columns are regular columns i.e vector

Comment: @Marie Do you have any `list` column or `matrix` as column.  Also, is it a `data.frame` or `tibble`

Comment: Thank you for your patience, I am very new to R.  No they are all characters. It is a data.frame.

Comment: @Marie can you change the expression as in the update

Comment: @Marie Code should have worked on your original data based on the description

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231908/discussion-between-marie-and-akrun).

Answer (score 3):

You could use the `na_if` function from `dplyr`. Note that the dot changes the type of your columns to be `char` which might not be what you want afterwards! The following code finds all `char` columns, replaces `.` with `NA` and converts the column to be numeric:

```
df <- df %>%
    mutate(across(where(is.character), ~as.numeric(na_if(., "."))))
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is an alternativ with `set_na` from `sjlabelled` package. Note the columns will remain as character type.

```
library(sjlabelled)
set_na(df, na = ".", as.tag = FALSE)
```

Output:

```
ITEM1 ITEM2 ITEM3 ITEM4 ITEM5
1     6     1     4  <NA>     1
2     8     6     2     3     6
3  <NA>     9     5     2     9
```