# how to convert all <NotAvailable> to <NA>

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have this df

```
PoolQC          Fence           MiscFeature
<chr>           <chr>           <chhr>
<NOT AVAILABLE> <NOT AVAILABLE> <NOT AVAILABLE>     
<NOT AVAILABLE> <NOT AVAILABLE> <NOT AVAILABLE>     
<NOT AVAILABLE> <NOT AVAILABLE> <NOT AVAILABLE>     
<NOT AVAILABLE> <NOT AVAILABLE> <NOT AVAILABLE>     
<NOT AVAILABLE> <NOT AVAILABLE> <NOT AVAILABLE>     
<NOT AVAILABLE> MnPrv           Shed        
<NOT AVAILABLE> <NOT AVAILABLE> <NOT AVAILABLE>     
<NOT AVAILABLE> <NOT AVAILABLE> Shed        
<NOT AVAILABLE> <NOT AVAILABLE> <NOT AVAILABLE>     
<NOT AVAILABLE> <NOT AVAILABLE> <NOT AVAILABLE>
```

how do I convert this all NOT AVAILABLE to NA, so that if I run this code

```
df %>% 
  is.na() %>% 
  colSums() %>% 
  sort(decreasing = TRUE)
```

it can detect the NA value

or, can I convert it by csv files reading?

```
df = read.csv("C:/Users/x.csv", sep = ";")
```

Comment: consider checking my answer again, I've updated it to account for your question on reading NA strings during `read.csv`. Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replacing character values with NA in a data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3357743/replacing-character-values-with-na-in-a-data-frame)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say I have the following data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(foo=c("<NOT AVAILABLE>", 2), bar=c(3, "<NOT AVAILABLE>"))
```

[image]

Replacing all `<NOT AVAILABLE>` occurrences with `NA`:

```
df[df == "<NOT AVAILABLE>"] <- NA
```

Then:

[image]

For your second question, you can set specific strings to be interpreted as NA during `read.csv`. Example:

```
result = read.csv(file, na.strings = "<NOT AVAILABLE>")
```